# python join one is to many

Tags: python, excel, join, one-to-many

How do I create a one is to many relationship using python.

I have Excel Table A which has a common field (X) with Excel Table B.

The X values in Table A are unique. The X values in Table B appear multiple times.

I want to a code to go through the values in Table B and every time there is a match with table A, output a join of the row in Table C.

Someone on this forum suggested using
`tableA.merge(tableB, left_on='x1', right_on='X2')` but it does not work for what I require.

As an example if I have a value of 10 in the X field of Table A it can appear multiple times in table B. every time it appears in Table B i want a join done with table A.

Comment: [ask] [help] [mre]

Comment: i solved this using  "pd.merge(tableB,tableA, on=['X'])"

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer, not as a comment. You can accept it after a while. But please act on [answer] & [help]. Eg don't just dump code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this using `pd.merge(tableB,tableA, on=['X'])`